# Downloading data only once and is then accessible throughout the app ; NSUserDefaults vs Singleton

Tags: ios, singleton, nsuserdefaults

I must download an array of content from a web service only once when the app launches. This data will then need to be accessible throughout the app at a later stage. The reason I need to download it on each launch is that the content can be changed at any time.

I was considering storing this array in NSUserDefaults, as it can be accessible anyway. But I also considered creating a singleton class. From what I can understand, NSUserDefaults IS a singleton itself.

Is using NSUserDefaults bad practice over creating a Singleton class for my case?

Comment: if you have more complex data then NSUserDefaults will not work properly and you get your app more weight. Use a global  array for storing data or use singleton .....

Comment: NO,using global array or singleton would not serve the purpose as they will loose all their content once app is terminated. If there  is some problem while using NSUserDefaults (highly unlikely) ,use Sqlite to store content.   NSUserDefaults can serve the purpose easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if `NSUserDefaults` is really implemented with a Singleton pattern. `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` maybe is.

The advantage of using `NSUserDefaults` is that you can store the data you've downloaded in the users device for later use, specially if the device is not connected to the internet when launching your app some other time.

If the construction of the objects you init through this data takes a considering time to be made, I suggest you use both `NSUserDefaults` for storing offline data and Singleton to make sure everything is going to be built in your app launch only.

Also is important to consider that `NSUserDefaults` can only store `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. If your data is not of those kinds, I suggest you save a file in the users device.

Singleton implementation:

```
@implementation Singleton

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        //initialization
    }
    return self;
}


+(id)allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone{
    return [self init];
}

+(Singleton *)sharedInstance{
    static Singleton *instance=nil;
    if(!instance){
        instance = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Also I recommend you use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for the WebService call. It handles the threading and stuff so that the user won't have to wait until the call is complete to open your app. While it isn't complete, use the previous downloaded data to open the app.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Im `NSURLSession` instead of `AFNetworking` and `NSURLConnection.` It Apples own method, and it implements many of the same as `AFNetworking`

Comment: @Gman Thanks! I didn't know about these classes.. i'm going to check how it works! i know that there's also `UNIRest`, but i don't think it is better than any one of those...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using `NSUserDefaults` for storing this data is that its value persists across multiple invocations of your application. However, your app would immediately replace the previously stored data with whatever comes from the server on start-up, so the data that has been loaded previously becomes a useless burden on the storage of the device.

Of course a big plus of storing the data in `NSUserDefaults` is that your application can have some data when there is no connectivity. If running on potentially obsolete data is better than not running at all, `NSUserDefaults` is a valid choice.

If you need to persist data only for as long as your app is running, using a singleton is a more optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

NSUSerDefaults would be better as they somewhat behave like a persisting database as they don't loose their content after app's termination while singleton doesn't have this ability.

One advice , if you can alter structure of XML being received or your team working on XML creation part, it would be very convenient for you if you ask them to add one tag like  "version = 1.0". Every time you open your app, download the data , simply check the version has changed or not, if changed then update your NSUserDefault content otherwise use old content. Just adding one tag just to check version of XML can save a lot pain.